# jquery ui #datepicker call infinite times

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

i am developing a events clasification. The date is one of them. i have jquery-UI datepicker, however this function just calls twice and the function inside on- select just works twice. All the sintax works fine but i need more twice. How can i resolve this?`

```
 $(document).on('focus',"#datepicker", function(){ 
          $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["es"]);
          $(this).removeAttr('datepicker');
           $(this).datepicker({
      firstDay: 1,
      dateFormat: "MM dd, yy",
      monthNames: [ "Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre" ],
      onSelect: function() { 
  var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
  var start = new Date(date.getFullYear(), 0, 0);
  var diff = date - start;
  var oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
  var dayy = Math.floor((diff / oneDay));

$(".fechae").each(function(){
$(".pin").hide();
$(".pin").removeClass('mostar');
var i= parseInt($(this).find("h2").text());
var f = parseInt($(this).find("p").text()); 
var $pin = $(this).parent(".pin");
if ( i<dayy && dayy <f ){
  $pin.addClass("menealo");
}
if ($pin.hasClass("visible")){
  $(".menealo.visible").show();

}else{
  $(".menealo").show();

} 
      });
```

}});
      });

The variables are days of year numbers.

Comment: Clear me on this - the event is firing twice and you want the datepicker to fire once for each focus? or is it other way around?

Comment: Yes, I want that the "onselect" function works  each time that the person choose a different date.  On("focus") is the way that i can manipulate a dinamically elements inside #datepicker, it is a option for  to use On() that i've found.

Answer (score 0):

From what I get is, the datepicker is called multiple times but you need the datepicker creation calls in `onfocus` because the data is dynamic.

There can be many ways to avoid this - create the data reading part in separate function, or destroy the datepicker every time you bind the new one. I'm going with later option here (more because I'm lazy, but I suggest use former solution) -

All you need is to add this line of code before date picker creation -

```
$(this).datepicker('destroy');
$(this).datepicker({
...
...
```

This will reset the datepicker on each focus and then recreate it with new data.

If this is not what you wanted please elaborate and also refine the question.